# Can I add an existing data template to a control's resources?

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls, decimal, datatemplate

I currently have a data template I apply to cells to get them styled a certain way:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="percentageCellContentTemplate4">
    <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="17" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="-1,-1,-1,-1" Background="White" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PercentScale4}, ConverterParameter=' \{0:P\}'}" ToolTip="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now I have a case where I need to add this as a typed template within a datagrid's resources. Currently, this is working:

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
          <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type s:Decimal}">
              <!-- This is exactly percentageCellContentTemplate4 - if someone can find a way to inherit this dataTemplate, free poutine. -->
              <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="17" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="-1,-1,-1,-1" Background="White" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PercentScale4}, ConverterParameter=' \{0:P\}'}" ToolTip="{Binding}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ResourceDictionary>
</xcdg:DataGridControl.Resources>
```

Can anyone think of a way that I avoid copy pasting the exact same template here and similar places where I need it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type s:Decimal}">
    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource percentageCellContentTemplate4}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

**Edit:** Tested it and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

While I think H.B.'s answer should work, two other possibilities come to mind (don't have WPF at hand right now) which can work out:

- extract all things you set on the TextBox to a style which you can then apply in both situations
- define the textblock itself as a resource and reference it in the two templates